# PHP Oracle Connectivity for different Host

Tags: php, oracle11g, database-connection

I have two database MySQL and Oracle under different domains

What i have to do is to take records from MySQL table to Oracle table
but i am unable to connect them

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

I Tried

```
$conn = oci_connect('username','password','xxx.xxx.x.xx:1521/dbName');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

**Note :** I am not working on localhost.. i write my code in editor and upload it to my domain

Thank You

Comment: You have to install OCI8 : http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php

Comment: i have downloaded instantclient.11.2 and put it to C:\program files\instantclient.11.2, i have set environment variable path to C:\program files\instantclient.11.2 .... is it ok or what i have to do next ?

Comment: *If using Instant Client, set the system PATH environment variable to the Oracle library directory.*

Comment: its working locally but need to active `extension=php_oci8.dll` on server but i dont have access to my php.ini, how can i make it active using .htaccess or anyhow ??

Comment: You can't activate an extension via `.htaccess`. You must contact server administrator to modify `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

After all i found the solution

1. download Oracle Instant Client as per your requirement. [Download Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

   i downloaded Basic Lite verson for 32-bit Windows [Basic Lite 11.2.0.4.0.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)
2. Extract this zip file to any path
   i used `C:\wamp\www\instantclient_11_2`
3. Now change the environmental variable
   goto `Control Panal > System > Advance System Setting > Advanced > Environmental Variables` under `System Variable` find and select `Path` click `edit`, write your Oracle Instant Client path `C:\wamp\www\instantclient_11_2` (as defined in step-2) inside `variable value`
4. Open your `php.ini` file and find `;extension=php_oci8.dll` for Oracle 10g or `;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll` for Oracle 11g
5. Remove `;` from `;extension=php_oci8.dll` for Oracle 10g or from `;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll` if u using Oracle 11g
6. for `PDO` remove `;` from `;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll`
7. Save php.ini file and restart wamp server

Now You are ready to use your `oci_connect statements` or `PDO statements`